# Database design: different precision level to describe a table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a DB and I cannot figure out how to model the following situation:

- There is a main table that is called "Transaction".
- Every transaction has a "Status" to describe it.
- Every status has 1 or 2 "Substatus" to describe it.
- A "Substatus" can have a "Subsubstatus" to describe it.

Moreover I need to express in the model that every "substatus" or "subsubstatus" is strictly link to its master table: indeed for a given "substatus" there is only one status possible.

The link between "Status" , "Substatus" and "Subsubstatus" seems logically like that:

- Status : STA_Id,STA_Name
- Substatus : SST_Id,*STA_Id*,SST_Name
- Subsubstatus : SSS_Id,*SST_Id*,SSS_Name

But the problem is the way to link that to "Transaction" table, taking into account that it can have 2 substatus and a subsubstatus.

I thought of linking "Subsubstatus" to "Transaction" but it forces me to give a subsubstatus to every transaction that is not really the case.

If you have an idea about that, it would be awesome!

Comment: do/will the relationships between statuses change? What would happen to invalidated transactions?

Comment: No , the relationshipes are fixed. What do you mean by "invalidated"?

Comment: Well, if the relationship between statuses changed some combination that was previously allowed be become disallowed. Any transaction based on the disallowed combination would then have an invalid combination of statuses.

Comment: ok, I got that, but statuses doesn't change and disallowed combination, to me, musn't be feasible in the DB

Comment: At what level should the status name be unique? Globally, per transaction (i.e. hierarchy) or per parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are desrcribing several things.

1. `Transaction` has a `Status`, a `SubStatus` and a `SubSubStatus`.
2. There is a parent child relationship between `Status` and `SubStatus`.
3. These is a parent child realtionship between `SubStatus` and `SubSubStatus`.
4. A `Transaction`'s `Substatus` is contrained by its `Status`, defined by the realtionship between `Status` and `SubStatus`.
5. A `Transaction`'s `SubSubStatus` is constrained by its `SubStatus`, defined by the realtionship between `SubStatus` and `SubSubStatus`.

Points 1, 2 and 3 are obviously defined by appropriate foriegn keys.

Points 4, and 5 will need to be be defined by more complicated contraints. These contraints will depend on how your database is implemented.

---

Alternatively you could denormalise all valid combinations into a single entity. This would make it easy to assure a `Transaction` has a valid combination but problematic when the relationship between statuses change.

Comment: It is a good idea , as there is a very finite number of combinations. But it makes the search by status or (sub)*status heavy no? It makes me crazy that I cannot find any normal modelisation for a quite normal problem..

Comment: @Jean, actually, I think that if you use a abstract id on the `ValidCombinations` it actually makes searching lighter. Step 1, get the id of my valid combination (this is a small table.), Step 2, use the id of the valid combination to select all transactions.

Comment: It makes sense, I think i'm going to go for that solution. It doesn't look like the classical design but I can't see why it wouldn't work. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Store the all the (sub)*statuses in the same table.

```
STA_Id,STA_Name,*SuperStatus_ID*
```

You might also want an extra field, `STA_Depth` to indicate how many sub levels you are down.

Comment: As I need to explore transactions by their status or (sub)*status via stored procedures, won't it be very messy like that?

Comment: Somewhat, you will need to join this table back to itself.  This is a normalization/denormalization issue, doing it like I describe ensures consistency.  But keeping explicit links to the top makes for faster querries.  To do the actual join you will want either a recursive query or using the STA_Depth field.

Answer (score 0):

Make another table and join subsubstatus and transection table in that.such as

- trans_subsubstatus SSS_Id,SST_Id,STA_Id
  It is easy to maintain normal table than a complax one

Comment: If I do that I loose the constraint between levels of statuses: for example : status (0,n) -------- (1,1) substatus

Comment: you don't lose constraint use foreign key in this table with other tables

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

*(NOTE: There is also `F2` in front of Status.TransactionId, but I couldn't show it above due to the limitation of the diagramming tool I used.)*

Legend:

- `F1`: The Status table references (via FOREIGN KEY) the Transaction table.
- `F2`: The Status table references itself (SuperStatusName refernces StatusName and TransactionId references itself).
- `PK`: Denotes primary keys.

The Status table represents both statuses and sub-statuses. It allows for a transaction to have unlimited number of statuses<sup>1</sup>, for each status to have unlimited number of sub-statuses etc...

Since we have used the identifying relationships and the resulting composite natural keys, all statuses (at all levels of hierarchy) of the same transaction share the same TransactionId. This makes it very easy to get the set of all statuses of the given transaction. However, putting these statuses in the correct order requires recursive querying.

It also makes it very easy to query in the opposite direction and find the transaction of the given status.

In addition to that, given StatusName can appear only once per transaction (i.e. two statuses of the same transaction cannot share the same name, even if they are at different levels of hierarchy).<sup>2</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> If you really want to limit to only 2 statuses at the database level, that is possible, but would complicate the conceptually simple model above and would unnecessarily limit you should the requirements change in the future.*

*<sup>2</sup> This may or may not be what you wanted. If you didn't, the model above can be changed accordingly.*

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and elaborated answer! But in my case I have the relationship Transaction (1,1) ----- (0,n).. So the FK StatusName should be in Transaction. And with this configuration we cannot have a recursive reference like F2 without having an abstract ID that lead to having all possible combinations of statuses and substatuses in a table like @Jodrel suggests

Comment: _"But in my case I have the relationship Transaction (1,1) ----- (0,n).. So the FK StatusName should be in Transaction."_ - No it shouldn't. Foreign key is at the "N" endpoint and it references a key from the "1" endpoint. _"And with this configuration we cannot have a recursive reference like F2 without having an abstract ID that lead to having all possible combinations of statuses and substatuses"_ - Sorry I don't understand this requirement nor why ID is required nor why it would be a bad thing. Are you saying you need to pick from a pre-existing set of hierarchies?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong;Transaction must have at least 1 Status and at maximum 1:(1,1) And Status can have 0 Transaction or unlimited number of it (0,n). Then how can a status be linked to several transaction if the transactionID is in the status table as foreign key?

Comment: @Jean In your previous comment, you said: _"Transaction (1,1) ----- (0,n)"_. What you just described is the opposite.

Comment: my bad, it's been long time since school.. I forgot a little bit how to describe relationship^..